# Deploy ASP MVC web page into ASPX website using iFrame

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iframe

Just a quick run through. I have deployed an ASP.NET MVC web page onto IIS7. When I "Browse" the page it opens my web browser and it displays the page. This page will be merged with another ASPX website. Using the following iFrame tag I implemented the page onto the site:

When I open the ASPX website the page then successfully displays but none of my MVC functions respond. Using Fiddler from Telerik I traced the HTTP URL flow and it throws out an Error 404 "Page not Found" while the page is still visible through the iframe.

Is there something I need to incorporate before adding the iframe to the ASPX website inside the MVC solution?

I would appreciate any assistance regarding this

Comment: I think you forgot to paste your HTML...

Comment: @user1859022 I do not have access to the ASP.NET website HTML but I can share my MVC page HTML if that would help?

Comment: probably not - can you reproduce the problem in your development environment (by creating an aspx page with an iframe of your own)?

Comment: @user1859022 That might help. I will let you know if that works but is there no other integration needed for this to work? As far as my knowledge goes it should be fine